# How can I check all the possible roots of a polynomial equation?

Tags: algorithm, maxima

I am working on writing a program to check all the possible roots of a polynomial equation. First I need to find all the possible roots and then check which root satisfies the given equation, as per theory. Until now I am able to find the integers divisors of the constant term (i.e, r) and the divisors of the coefficient of highest power (i.e.,s), the possible roots should be r/s. I am unable to make this list.

Here is my program (I am new to maxima, there may be a better code available)

```
kill(all)$ 
A:makelist(k,k,-5,5)$
    a0:4$
    an:5$
    m:zeromatrix(1,length(A))$ 
    n:zeromatrix(1,length(A))$
    for i:1 thru length(A) do(
    if mod(a0,A[i])=0 then 
    m[1,i]:A[i],
    if mod(an,A[i])=0 then 
    n[1,i]:A[i]); 
    disp("The divisors of a0 are",m)$ 
    disp("The divisors of an are",n)$ 
    for i:1 thru 11 do(
    for j:1 thru 11 do(
    disp(m[1,i]/n[1,j])));
```

The last `disp` statement should give the values, r/s, as either a matrix or list. once that happens I can check the elements in the list for the equation f(x)=0 and get the roots. can somebody help me?

Comment: What output did you expect to see, and what output did you actually get? Please paste all of that into your question, it will help others understand what you're trying to do. Also, it will help a lot if you explicitly state what is the equation you are trying to solve.

Comment: "the possible roots should be r/s" this is false. These are only rational roots.

Comment: kill(all)$ 
A:makelist(k,k,-5,5)$
    a0:4$
    an:5$
    m:zeromatrix(1,length(A))$ 
    n:zeromatrix(1,length(A))$
    for i:1 thru length(A) do(
    if mod(a0,A[i])=0 then 
    m[1,i]:A[i],
    if mod(an,A[i])=0 then 
    n[1,i]:A[i]); 
    disp("The divisors of a0 are",m)$ 
    disp("The divisors of an are",n)$ 
    for i:1 thru 11 do(
    for j:1 thru 11 do(
    disp(m[1,i]/n[1,j])));

Comment: Thank you enedil. I am sorry I am actually checking for all the possible rational roots only

Comment: Thank you Robert.  Actually I am trying to find all the possible rational roots of f[x]:=5*x^3+8*x^2+6*x-4 and expecting the output as [-1,1,-1/5.1/5.-2,2,-2/5,2/5,-4,4,-4/5,4/5]. But what I am getting is a display of all these values separately and each one repeated twice. The output is little too long to paste here.                                                             Hope I can get some help